# Scant or Sparse description?

Tags: synonyms

Do I use the adjective scant or sparse in order to describe the noun "description" or "details", such as 'details in a note' or 'description of a problem'?  From the dictionary meanings (insufficiency for scant and meagreness, thin dispersal for sparse), I get the impression that sparse may be used for countable nouns.

thanks and regards,

SS

Answer (score 1):

"Scant" describes amount relative to need or requirement; a scant description is one insufficient (or barely sufficient) to specify its subject, and scant details are not as many details as might be desirable.

"Sparse" describes distribution, frequency, or other relations to the (physical, organizational, or metaphorical) space it is filling up; a sparse description is one where the aspects that are described are far outnumbered by the aspects that are left undescribed, and sparse details refers to a small subset of all the potential details.